# If I have a file descriptor with an integer value above 1024, can select() still work on it?

Tags: c, linux, select, unix-socket, bsd

The man page for `select()` states:

> **WARNING**: `select()` can monitor only file descriptors numbers that are less than `FD_SETSIZE` (1024)—an unreasonably low limit for many modern applications.

This is very vague, I understand that select can only monitor 1024 file descriptors, but what if I want it to monitor a single file descriptor, a descriptor with an integer value greater than 1024.

For context, I am writing a program that has a timeout on a file descriptor of 15 seconds, and this file descriptor may have an integer value greater than 1024. From what I heard a few months ago, `select()` seems like a prime choice for this task.

I will only be monitoring one file descriptor, say it is called `int fd` and `fd == 65533`. Can select watch this single descriptor 65533?

Comment: The next sentence in the docs you omitted is "all modern applications should instead use poll or epoll". Seems like `poll` can do what you want and is encouraged over `select` yeah?

Comment: Please elaborate your reasons for wanting to use `select()` instead of `poll()` - or confirm that @CollinD has provided the solution and should turn it into an answer post for the options that offers.

Comment: @Yunnosch Dude, the question was posted half an hour ago. You should give people *at least* 48 hours to react to anything posted here, especially on weekends.

Comment: @zwol I do not share your feeling of urgency with my comment. I wanted to add "please explain in case of intention" to the assumption made by CollinD, which seems plausible but stays an assumption, that OP is simply not aware of the alternative. The two possibilites to answer to my comment both habe no expiry date or ultimatum attached. But I see now that this impression can occur, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

The manpage might give you the impression that 1024 is a hard upper limit for `select`, but that's not true. Some C libraries let you `#define FD_SETSIZE` yourself, before including `sys/select.h`, and thus enlarge `fd_set`. Even if you don't have one of those C libraries, nothing stops you from defining your *own*, larger fd_set-like data type. The kernel does not know how big the C library defined `fd_set` to be: instead it trusts the `nfds` argument to tell it how many bits there are.

However, if you only have one fd to monitor, you should definitely use `poll()` instead of `select()`, because it's both simpler to use, and more efficient, for small numbers of fds. And if you have *many* fds to monitor, `epoll` or `kqueue` or similar will be more efficient than either `poll` or `select`. So it usually isn't worth bothering to work around the size of `fd_set`.